# Reset Button is not working in Stop watch using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, stopwatch

Reset Button is not resetting but it is working as stop button can anybody help me,whats wrong  with this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Timer</title>
        <script>            
            var sec = 0;
            var min = 0;
            var hour = 0;
            var theResult = "";
            function WatchOperations(key) {
                sec++;
                if (sec == 60) {
                    sec = 0;
                    min = min + 1; }
                else {
                    min = min; }
                if (min == 60) {
                    min = 0; 
                    hour += 1; 
                }
                if (sec<=9) {
                    sec = "0" + sec;
                }
                document.getElementById("stopwatch").value = ((hour<=9) ? "0"+hour : hour) + " : " + ((min<=9) ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + sec;
                if (key == "Start") {
                    document.getElementById("startButton").value = "Stop ";
                }
                if (key == "Stop ") {
                    document.getElementById("startButton").value = "Start"; 
                    sec = sec-1; sec--; 
                }
                if (document.getElementById("startButton").value == "Start") {
                    return true; 
                }
                SD=window.setTimeout("WatchOperations();", 1000);
                theResult = document.getElementById("stopwatch").value;
            }
            function resetIt() {
                sec = 0;
                min = 0;
                hour = 0;                
                if (document.getElementById("startButton").value == "Stop ") {
                    document.getElementById("startButton").value = "Start";
                    window.clearTimeout(SD);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td align="right"><input type="text" size="12" id="stopwatch" value="00 : 00 : 00" style="text-align:center" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><input type="button" id="startButton" value="Start" onclick="WatchOperations(this.value);"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="resetButton" value="Reset" onclick="resetIt()"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line document.getElementById("stopwatch").value = "00 : 00 : 00"; in this method resetIt
to reset stopwatch

```
function resetIt() {
            sec = 0;
            min = 0;
            hour = 0;                
            if (document.getElementById("startButton").value == "Stop ") {
                document.getElementById("startButton").value = "Start";
        document.getElementById("stopwatch").value = "00 : 00 : 00";
                window.clearTimeout(SD);
            }
        }
```

if you dont want to stop the watch you need to comment "window.clearTimeout(SD);" this line in this method

Answer (score 1):

First you need to declare `clearTimeout()` ID which is `SD` globally. As you're using it in more than one function: 
Second You have to set `stopwatch` to default value which is `"00 : 00 : 00"` when you click on reset.

```
function resetIt() {
    sec = 0;
    min = 0;
    hour = 0;
    if (document.getElementById("startButton").value == "Stop ") {
        document.getElementById("startButton").value = "Start";
        window.clearTimeout(SD);
        document.getElementById("stopwatch").value = "00 : 00 : 00"; // Changed
    }
}
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FzUVj/)

Answer (score 1):

I would say to reset the stopwatch textbox value at the outside of the if condition block which will ensure the reset button works even when the Stop button is clicked.

```js
function resetIt() {
   sec = 0;
   min = 0;
   hour = 0;                
   if (document.getElementById("startButton").value == "Stop ") {
     document.getElementById("startButton").value = "Start";
     window.clearTimeout(SD);
   }
     document.getElementById("stopwatch").value = "00 : 00 : 00";
}
```

Also, I see you used ***sec--;*** when the button is **Stop**. I don't think that is required here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove SD from all of the code where ever you used,without that also program will run perfectly.